# Why can't I change my password in system settings? Nexus 6p Resurrection Remix Pie

Tags: security, 9.0-pie, nexus-6p, pattern-lock

After entering the wrong password too many times in VPN settings, I can't enter my password in settings. Whenever I do, I get sent back to the previous page. I can't even change my password!

Comment: is it possible to edit VPN profile data? Also please remind that you're on custom ROM and may have such bugs and please contact develping team.

Comment: It used to be working and stopped after I screwed with the VPN settings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I factory reset and it started working again!